# JS Как добраться до нужного ключа в объекте из данных в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть строка

```
var str = "key1.key2.key3";
```

Есть объект

```
var obj = {
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: false
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно добраться до ключа в `obj.key1.key2.key3` из указанных в строке ключей через точку и изменить значение на другое.

Вариант ответа и для старых браузеров:

```
str = str.split(".");
var strLng = str.length;
var tmp = obj;
for(var strIdx = 0; strIdx < strLng; strIdx++) {
    if(strIdx < strLng - 1) {
        tmp = tmp[str[strIdx]];
    } else {
        tmp[str[strIdx]] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

один из вариантов -

```js
var str = "key1.key2.key3";
var obj = {
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: false
        }
    }
}

const getValueByPath = ( source, path ) => str.split('.').reduce( ( object, prop ) => object = object[ prop ] , source );
const setValueByPath = ( source, path, value ) => str.split('.').reduce( ( object, prop, index, array ) => {
  if( index < array.length - 1 ){
    object = object[ prop ]
  }else{
    object[ prop ] = value;
  }
  
  return object;
} , source );

setValueByPath( obj, str, true )
console.log( getValueByPath( obj, str ) );
```

И с помощью рекурсии -

```js
var str = "key1.key2.key3";
var obj = {
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: false
        }
    }
}

const setValueByPath = ( object, keys, value ) =>
   keys.length > 1 ? 
   setValueByPath( object = object[ keys.shift() ], keys, value ) :
   object[ keys.shift() ] = value;

const getValueByPath = ( object, keys ) => 
   keys.length > 1 ?
   getValueByPath( object = object[ keys.shift() ], keys ) :
   object[ keys.shift() ];

let path = str.split('.');

setValueByPath( obj, [ ...path ], "new value" );

console.log( getValueByPath( obj, [ ...path ] ) );
```

Comment: я так и не понял как в obj.key1.key2.key3 изменить значение

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать цикл для прохода по объекту вглубину по ключам, до предпоследнего. Затем, получив предпоследний объект, заменить значение по последнему ключу.

```
function set_value( object, path, new_value ){
   const names = path.split( '.' );    
   const last_key = names.pop();
   const obj_before_last = 0 in names ? get_value( object, names.join('.') ) : object;
   obj_before_last[ last_key ] = new_value;   
   return object
}

function get_value( object, path ){
   const names = path.split( '.' );
   let cur_obj = object;
   for( let i = 0; i < names.length; i++ )
       cur_obj = cur_obj[ names[ i ] ]; 
   return cur_obj;
}
//изменять так   
set_value( { a: { b: { c: false } } }, "a.b.c", true ); //result {a:{b:{c:true}}}
set_value( { a: 'foo' }, "a", 'boo' );                  //result {a:'boo'}
```

Либо можно воспользоваться одной из десяток библиотек в npm. 
К примеру [Peek](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peek) или [deep-property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-property)