# Обращение к объекту в объекте через его полный адрес, переданный в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```
let obj = {a:{b:{c:10}}};
```

Получить значение `c` можно через

```
obj["a"]["b"]["c"];
obj.a.b.c;
```

Есть ли возможность обратиться к `c` через что-то вроде этого 
`obj["a.b.c"]` ?

Comment: В библиотеке `lodash` есть функция `get`, которая позволяет сделать именно это. Но вы ее и сами написать можете. А так, вообще, нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581539/js-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {a: {b: {c: 10}}};

function get(obj, path, defaultVal) {
  return path.split(".").reduce((acc, prop) => (acc && prop !== "" ? acc[prop] : acc), obj) || defaultVal
}

console.log(get(obj, "", "defaultValue"));
console.log(get(obj, "a.b"));
console.log(get(obj, "a.b.c"));

console.log(get(obj, "c.a.c", "defaultValue"));




obj.get = get.bind(null, obj);

console.log(obj.get(""));
console.log(obj.get("a.b"));
console.log(obj.get("b", "defaultValue"));
```

```js
function get(path, defaultVal) {
  return path.split(".").reduce((acc, prop) => (acc && prop !== "" ? acc[prop] : acc), this) || defaultVal
}

Object.prototype.get = Object.prototype.get || get;

let obj = {a: {b: {foo: "foo"}, boo: "boo"}}

console.log(obj.get("a.b.foo"));
console.log(obj.get("a.boo"));
console.log(obj.get("a.boo.foo", "default value"));
```

Comment: метода set не хватает

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object.prototype.setByPath = function (keys, value, createTree=true){

        let object = this;
        if(typeof keys === 'string'){ keys = keys.split('.')}
        while(keys.length > 1){
            let key = keys.shift();
            if(createTree && !object[key]){ object[key] = new Object; } 
            object = object[key];
        }
        return object[keys.shift()]=value;
    }

    Object.prototype.getByPath = function (keys, defValue){

        let object = this;
        if(typeof keys === 'string'){ keys = keys.split('.')}
        while(keys.length > 1 && object){
            object = object[keys.shift()];
        }
        if(!object){return defValue;}
        return object[keys.shift()];
    }


let obj = {a: {b: {c: 10}}};
obj.setByPath("a.b.c", 15);
console.log(obj.getByPath("a.b.c"));
```